# permission denied when using batch

Tags: 7, batch-operations, xml-sitemap

I have just switched over a site live and I'm having problems regenerating the XML sitemap.

When I try, I get:

`You are not authorized to access this page.`

The URL is: `www.example.com/batch?op=start&id=207`

What could be causing this?

Thanks

EDIT:
I have created a new role with every single permission and assigned the user I'm logged in with to this role. Still no luck1

Comment: btw, you can also generate xmlsitemap via drush (given that you have access to shell and drush), I prefer that.

Comment: I don't have shell access or Drush

Comment: Does anyone know why I'm getting permission denied?

Answer (score 1):

Had to manually run the cron via the browser to generate.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue might be related to a small value in max_allowed_packet parameter in your MySql configuration. Drupal cannot store correctly the batch operation data and the subsequent execution fails with a "permission denied" error.

There's an issue [here](https://drupal.org/node/434032), discussing the problem.

If you cannot edit your MySql configuration (like me), there's a patch at [message #41](https://drupal.org/node/434032#comment-2286988) that helped me bypass that issue. It's a couple of lines that you can modify by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with a similar issue and eventually realized that I had created a folder named batch in my Drupal root, which interfered with the resolution of the "/batch/" path in the request.  Generally speaking, I have found that menu router entries that match actual folder names in your Drupal install seem to cause odd behavior...best to avoid that.